# Delete annotations in pgn games

Tags: pgn, chessbase, annotation

Using ChessBase 13, I saved a bunch of games in PGN format. Is there a simple way to suppress the comments of all annotated games? I would like to avoid doing it one by one.

Comment: pgnextract can easily do it.

Comment: pgnextract can surely do it easily but not for a poor windows user! I would be pleased to accept an answer that details how to achieve it (including how to properly install the program using windows 7). I tried to run the command `pgn-extract -C mygames.pgn` but without success...

Comment: What error did you have? I'm sure the `-C` command would work. I've been doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chessbase, copy the games to a temp database, right click the file, go to tools and select Unannotate db, then copy to the games to a pgn file.

Edited to note Unannotate doesn't work on pgn files directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Efficient solution. Note that the right click should be done in the cbh file before copying the game to the pgn file.

Comment: I'd copy them to a temp database first so you don't lose the annotations in the original db.

Answer (score 1):

Goto https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html#suppress and look for Suppress annotations in the output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again (unable to upvote for the moment). I am sure it works but I am not comfortable with a command line tool. So I was not able to make it. I downloaded `pgn-extract-17-21.exe`(using Windows 7) in the same folder that my pgn file. Then I ran the .exe file and I executed the command `pgn-extract C mygames.pgn` in the appearing windows shell but nothing happened. I would appreciate any help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kortchnoi You will need to start a console. Have you?

Comment: No I haven't. Can you recommend me one?